# PHP 5X.X is sending zero as value to any SOAP service

Tags: php, web-services

I have a webservice with one one method that reurns an objetc, the method is very simple `getObject(int id);`

I made a PHP client to test it:

```
     <?php
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "1"); // Set to zero to avoid caching WSDL
$soapClient = new SoapClient('http://localhost:8080/ws-tickets/tickets2?wsdl');  

$id = 2;

$result = $soapClient->get Ticket($id);    
print_r($result);
```

?>

Well, I debug the WS when it is called by this php client and I see that the parameter received by it is ZERO.

If in my database I create a record that has "0" as id, the phpclient will retrieve it perfectly and every data is printed as it supouse to be for the  `print_r($result);` command.

But, no mather wich parameter I send, it allways came to ZERO to the ws and I do not know what I am doing wrong

My Java WS is

```
@WebService
public class tickets2 {

   @EJB
   reciboDAO reciboDAO;




    public ticket getTicket(int id){



        recibo a = this.reciboDAO.getReciboporid(id);
        return a;

    } 

}
```

Comment: Can you try opening the URL in a browser and see what you get? If the server side returns zero - then probably the problem is with your server and not the PHP client.

Comment: When I open the URL i can see the correct WSDL in fact if I add a rcord to my database with a 0 in its ID the object contained is retrieved properly

Comment: Sounds like in your method "getTicket" the value of the parameter "id" is always getting set to zero. To test can you please do "id = 1;" before the line "recibo a = this...." in your Java class?

Comment: I did as you suggest and the webservice returns a correct object , I am still clueless of why it does not receive the parameter properly when called by php